# gets function is not reading my variable

Tags: c, gets

I noticed today that sometimes when I use the gets function my compiler simply ignores it.
OK. This is an example where gets works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char s[50];
    gets(s);
    puts(s);
}
```

Now if I make this simple change to my program, the function gets is ignored:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n;    
    printf("dati n:\n");    
    scanf("%d",&n);    
    char s[50];
    gets(s);
    puts(s);
}
```

"ignored" means that when i run the program the compiler reads the variable and then quits without reading my string. Why does that happen? Thank you.

Comment: The compiler should always ignore `gets`, on principle. Don't use it, it's unsafe.

Comment: Your compiler is right. Ignore `gets()`. Just use `fgets()`. :P

Comment: That's because `scanf()` "slurped" the digits you meant to read, which means that when it's `gets()`'s turn to read, nothing's left.

A side note: `gets()` is _extremely_ poor style. Prefer `fgets()` in the future. `gets()` is so unsafe that it was removed in the latest C standard.

Answer (score 5):

Your `scanf` only consumes the number you typed. Anything else after that *including* the carriage return/newline you typed, is left in the IO buffers.

So `gets` picks up whatever was left after the number (which is possibly just a newline character) and returns immediately.

As commenters have noted: don't use `gets`. It has actually been removed from the C standard (no longer in C11) since it is fundamentally unsafe. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: I am a beginnner, I read in the forums today that gets is dangerous, but I still used it because I don`t know the prototype of fgets.

Comment: Just type 'fgets' in your favorite search engine, you'll get lots of info, including official standards (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) and lots of examples.